# AM GM inequality using a relation

Tags: a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I am given a relation that for $a,b>0$ we have $$ab\leq \dfrac{a^p}{p}+\dfrac{b^q}{q}$$ where $ p$ and $ q$ satisfy $\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{q}=1$. Now how do I use this to prove the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: What if $p=q=2$?

Comment: then $2ab\leq a^2+b^2\leq (a+b)^2$

Comment: Yes, $ab \leqslant \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$. Isn't it familiar?

Comment: okay so we use that $\sqrt{ab}\leq ab$

Comment: Not exactly. We have that $\forall a,b > 0$, $ab \leqslant \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$. And we want to prove that $\forall x, y > 0$, $\sqrt{xy} \leqslant \frac{x+y}{2}$. Aren't they similar?

Comment: ohhhh...since it is true for all $x,y$ then it is true for $\sqrt{x}$ and$ \sqrt{y}$ also

Comment: Yes! If we let $a=\sqrt{x}$ and $b=\sqrt{y}$, then we have that $\forall x,y > 0$, $\sqrt{xy} \leqslant \frac{x+y}{2}$. And we can do it, because $x \to \sqrt{x}$ is a bijection between $(0,\infty)$ and $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3):

If you introduce $x=a^p$, $y=b^q$ $s=1/p$ and $t=1/q$, then this is the [weighted AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Generalizations):
$$
x^sy^t\leq sx+ty
$$
You can deduce this from the regular AM-GM for rational $s$ and $t$, but for real $s$ and $t$ you need some additional argument, like continuity.